# Evaluate the double integral of $F(x,y)=x^2+xy$, over the triangle with vertices $(0,0),(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I tried solving it but my answer gets different
when I integrate first with respect to $x$ and $y$ (like $dx \ dy$) I get $5/24$
and when I integrate first with respect to $y$ then $x$ (like $dy \ dx$) or by changing order of integration I get $3/8$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show details.

Comment: Something tells me your limits of integration may not be right.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, I was using wrong limits when integrating by y first and then x. I was taking 0 to x but instead it was from x to 1

Answer (score 1):

Draw a graph of it, what you have is the lines $y=0,y=x,x=0,x=1$ so that gives you:
$$0\le x\le 1,0\le y\le x$$ so your integral will be:
$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1\,\int\limits_{y=0}^x(x^2+xy)\,\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$
and you have to do it in this order, with these limits you have to do it in this order, otherwise it is the equivalent of $0\le x,y\le 1$ which is not correct